# What is the meaning of 33 koti in reference to Hindu gods?

Tags: gods, vedic-gods

In a TV series it was mentioned that 33 koti does not mean 33 crore which is what the general public including me know about the number of Hindu gods. It means 33 important gods which includes adityas , ashwinikumaras ,rudras and some more gods . Is this statement true ? If yes please explain and give details about the 33 important gods.